# How to read in html files with another method than file_get_contents() in codeigniter and send via html mail without getting shred?

Tags: file, codeigniter, html-email, phpmailer

Whenever i'm using file_get_contents() to pass a html-email-template `$body=file_get_contents($path);` as a variable to the phpmailer method `$mail->MsgHTML($body);` the mail gets shred.

How else to do? Would file_get_html() of the simple_html_dom script help? How to run that as library in codeigniter? What other possibilities are there? I would appreciate some advices, links etc.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch as I don't know what you mean by shred.

```
$mail->CharSet='utf-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
```